# PIP Prevent connection to pypi.python.org while doing installation from local folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pypi

On trying to do a install via PIP like below

```
sudo pip install --verbose -U --allow-unverified --no-index --find-links=/tmp/chef-cache/patroni patroni[zookeeper]==1.4.4
```

I am seeing pip is trying to connect to pypi.python.org

```
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/patroni/
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/patroni/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(99, 'Cannot assign requested address'))': /simple/patroni/
Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.python.org
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/patroni/'): Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(99, 'Cannot assign requested address'))': /simple/patroni/
Starting new HTTPS connection (3): pypi.python.org
```

The set-up does not have access to outside IP. Is there a way I can prevent pip from trying to connect to `pypi.python.org` ?

NOTE - The installation is happening fine. But it is taking more time as it is trying to connect to `pypi.python.org` and then getting timed out, thereby slowing the installation.

- pip version: 7.1.2
- Python version: 2.7.6
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an issue with PIP 7.1.2. The issue is not observed in the latest PIP 18.0.